# Why does my subscription trigger one time on one component but reliably on the other components that point to the same observable?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm new to Angular and am working on revamping map program we have and I'm running into a bizarre event.
There are 3 main component and each contains a subscription to the Query Component Observables

1.Query Component ($qs)

```
private idSelected = new ReplaySubject<string[]>(1);
public idSelected$: Observable<string[]> = this.idSelected.asObservable();

constructor(...) {
    this.configureSubscriptionServices();
}

private configureSubscriptionServices(){
    this.idSelected$.subscribe(id => {
        console.log("SUBSCRIBE: Query Service executed");
    }
}
public setIdSelected(id:string){
    this.idSelected.next(id);
}
```

2.Map Component

```
// ...
private configureSubscriptionServices(){
    this.$qs.idSelected$.subscribe(id => {
        console.log("SUBSCRIBE: Map executed");
    }
}
```

3.Table/Data Grid Component

```
// ...
private configureSubscriptionServices(){
    this.$qs.idSelected$.subscribe(id => {
        console.log("SUBSCRIBE: Data Table executed");
    }
}
```

The Query component is the main one that has the creation of the ReplaySubject and Observable creations.
Now...
What I'm working on is the selection of a record via the map or the table. When the user clicks on either point or row its method calls

```
this.$qs.setIdSelected(...some value...);
```

**Here is the oddity that I cannot figure out.**
1st click on the map causes all 3 subscriptions to trigger
2nd+ clicks on the map causes 2 subscriptions to trigger (map & Table) but not the main Query Component

I don't have any way to bring the code over to this system to post so I'm short handing it.
Does anyone have some kind of gotcha reason as to why this may occur.

I don't see any unsubscribes within the code, nor can I find any black hole catch(e) in the code. I've already cleaned them all out.

Comment: Obviously hard to diagnose without full code from query component. Must be something you've missed out as the short-hand code obviously looks fine. (aside from what I'm assuming are typos)

Comment: Probably typos because the code is on a different computer not on this network. Strange behavior that all fire the first time but subsequent calls only trigger the two child subscribers.

Comment: I would suggest moving the replay subject and it's methods into a service and making sure it is a singleton. Then inject it into everything that needs to listen / modify.